Sum data based on conditions from other columns
I have a SQL table like this:



ID
Level
Type
Value




A
ZZ
1
20


A
YY
1
10


C
XX
1
30


B
ZZ
1
40


B
XX
1
60


C
YY
1
100


D
WW
2
70


D
VV
2
90



For each 'Level', if its 'Type' = 1, I want to sum all the 'Value' associated with IDs that includes that level, even if the 'Value' isn't associated directly with that specific level. For example, for level ZZ, it would sum all values associated with IDs A and B, because these two IDs include level ZZ: ID A Level ZZ + ID A Level YY + ID B Level ZZ + ID B Level XX. (more details below).
My expected outcome would be a table like this:



Level
Value




ZZ
130


YY
160


XX
230



The table is calculates as follows:

Level ZZ: sum all values related to IDs A and B [20+10+40+60=130]
Level YY: sum all values related to IDs A and C [20+10+30+100=160]
Level XX: sum all values related to IDs B and C [30+40+60+100=230]
Levels WW and VV would not be included as they are type 2.

Thanks!

Please avoid using reserved keywords such as level as stated here for user defined structures

Start with getting the sums per ID, from thereon it gets easy-peasy.
with
  id_sums as
  (
    select id, sum(value) as sum_value
    from mytable
    group by id
  )
select t.levl, sum(s.sum_value) as total
from mytable t
join id_sums s on s.id = t.id
where t.type = 1
group by t.levl
order by t.levl;

The same can be done with a window function which you may or may not find more readable:
with
  with_sums as
  (
    select t.*, sum(value) over (partition by id) as id_sum_value
    from mytable t
    where type = 1
  )
select levl, sum(id_sum_value) as total
from with_sums
group by levl
order by levl;

(I've renamed your level column levl here, because LEVEL is a reserved word in Oracle.)
Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/bq0uJ06z

Thank you very much! It worked like a charm.

One option is to use LISTAGG() analytic function to get a list of IDs per Level (LVL). Use that list in a correlated subquery that will fetch you the totals.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl (      ID,    LVL,   TPE, VAL  ) AS
    ( Select 'A',   'ZZ',   1,  20 From Dual Union All
      Select 'A',   'YY',   1,  10 From Dual Union All
      Select 'C',   'XX',   1,  30 From Dual Union All
      Select 'B',   'ZZ',   1,  40 From Dual Union All
      Select 'B',   'XX',   1,  60 From Dual Union All
      Select 'C',   'YY',   1, 100 From Dual Union All
      Select 'D',   'WW',   2,  70 From Dual Union All
      Select 'D',   'VV',   2,  90 From Dual 
    )

--      S Q L :
SELECT l.LVL, (Select Sum(VAL) 
               From tbl
               Where InStr(',' || l.IDS || ',', ',' || ID || ',') > 0
              ) "TOTAL"
FROM ( Select  Distinct LVL,  
               LISTAGG(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( Order By ID ) Over( Partition By LVL ) "IDS"
       From    tbl
       Where   TPE = 1
     ) l
ORDER BY l.LVL Desc

/*  R e s u l t :
LVL TOTAL
--- -----
ZZ    130
YY    160
XX    230     */

